MUI DataGridPro onRowOrderChange doesn't work in mobile. Is there a way to implement row reordering in mobile(touchscreen) using datagrid?
I'm currently using MUI data-grid-pro v5.17.24.
The problem is that MUI DataGridPro onRowOrderChange, changing the row order doesn't work in mobile while it works fine in the Desktop.
I found out that mui datagrid doensn't support onRowOrderChange in mobile.
In the other parts, I'm using react-beautiful-dnd to change the list order, and it supports in mobile so it works fine.
But I can't use react-beautiful-dnd in this part, because I'm using valueGetter, preProcessEditCellProps in the datagrid to change the value of some particular columns.
In this kind of situation, is there a way to implement row reordering in mobile(touchscreen) using data grid?
